# PHP call hierarchy

Tags: php, netbeans

I am moving to PHP in a netbeans environment from Java in Eclipse. I love the 'call hierarchy' window in eclipse, does any php IDE (with priority on netbeans) have this functionality?

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: maybe love is too strong a word, but you get the picture...

Comment: Maybe you should explain what this feature does for those who aren't so familiar with Eclipse's features, or a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

[PHP storm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) does. I should try to call it for once, I guess :).

Anyway, it's a great tool from an old and reliable company (Jetbrains) and, yes, I do love it ;]

Comment: it's 45 days demo and if you're not convinced by then, after the trial it shuts down every half an hour, but that's it.